# Flask: Not Found The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I am just a beginner in this api creating with python and I was trying to create an api.

But when I run the code, it gives me the error : 404

****init**.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
```

**routes.py**

```
from flask_restful import Resource

from src import api


class Smoke(Resource):
    def get():
        return {'message': 'Ok'}, 200


api.add_resource(Smoke, '/')
```

**wsgi.py**

```
from src import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The routes.py file is never called, so the route is never bound to the api.
Change your wsgi.py file to:

**wsgi.py**

```
from src import app, api
from src import Smoke

if __name__ == '__main__':
    api.add_resource(Smoke, '/')
    app.run()
```